# Failure sending mail. - System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed

Tags: c#, web-services, email

I have used below code bit to send email from my web service

```
var emailMessage = new MailMessage(fromaAdress, toAdress)
{
   Subject = subject,
   IsBodyHtml = true,
   Body = body
};

var smtp = new SmtpClient()
{

   Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net",
   Port = 25,
   EnableSsl = false,
   DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
   UseDefaultCredentials = false,
   Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxx", "xxxxxx"),
   Timeout = 10000
};

smtp.Send(emailMessage);
```

1. Web service is work perfectly fine with staging server and Test server.
2. doesn't work and throw error on prod server(wen i use as a service form other 
   web applications).
3. But it dose work when i use application in same domain(xxx.com/sendmailTest app with xxx.com/sendmailservice).Environment difference is prod has SSL installed.I have changed the ssl enable 587 ports. still the same error.

Can some one help me to find the issue please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the PROD machine have a more strict firewall with ports closed? Have a look here: [SMTP Ports](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Email_Infrastructure/smtp_ports.html)
"Many hosting providers and ISPs block port 25 as a default practice. When trying to connect to smtp.sendgrid.net remember that ports 25, 2525, 587, and 465 are all available for use. You can connect via unencrypted or TLS on ports 25, 2525, and 587. You can also connect via SSL on port 465."

Comment: thanks Rick for quick reply. remember I can send email within same domain. No port or firewall issue i can look into.

Comment: try port 587 please